# Need to find infimum S!!

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

Why isn't the infimum of this -0.98 as that is in the lower bound set (-infinity,-0.98 included) and it is also the greatest lower bound but the answer is -1 and I don't understand why that is as yes it is in the lower bound set but it is not the greatest lower bound.

For some reason I'm not being able to work out the infimum properly and seemed to have totally blanked out.

Comment: How exactly are you coming up with the number -0.98? It's quite obvious that it *can't* be this, since there is an $n$ such that $-1\leq\cos(\pi\sqrt{n}/2)<-0.98.$  The periodicity of $\cos$ then allows you to take $n$ large enough so that $2/n$ is as small as you like.

Comment: @Taylor i'm using my calculator otherwise for n =2,3,4.. how would i dertermine the values the set takes

Comment: @Taylor, oh so can I take 2/n to be 0 and just work with the cos function to work out values in the set for large n?

Comment: Don't use the calculator for this. It will get you nowhere. Consider: the cosine term equals $-1$ for infinitely many $n$. Can you see which ones? And this is the smallest it can get. Now notice that the $2/n$ gets really, really small if $n$ is large. Put the two together.

Comment: ^ essentially, yes.  And using your calculator to plug in sample values is not an acceptable argument.  It is sometimes helpful for giving you intuition and an idea of what the answer should be, but in this situation you need to apply some additional reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\cos x\geq-1$ for all $x\in{\mathbb R}$ and ${2\over n}>0$ for all $n\in{\mathbb N}_{\geq1}$ it follows that
$$x_n:=\cos\left({\pi\sqrt{n}\over2}\right)+{2\over n}>-1\qquad(n\in{\mathbb N}_{\geq1})\ .$$
Therefore $-1$ is a lower bound of your set $S$.

Now $S$ contains "bad" $x_n$'s arbitrarily close to $-1$. To see this  consider the "special" $n$'s given by $$n_k:=4(2k+1)^2\qquad(k\geq1)\ .$$
The points
$$\eqalign{y_k:=x_{n_k}&=\cos\left({\pi\sqrt{4(2k+1)^2}\over2}\right)+{2\over 4(2k+1)^2}\cr &=
\cos\bigl((2k+1)\pi\bigr)+{1\over 2(2k+1)^2}=-1+{1\over 2(2k+1)^2}\cr}$$
all belong to $S$ and converge to $-1$ when $k\to\infty$. It follows that $S$ possesses no lower bound which is strictly bigger than $-1$. In other words: It follows that $\inf S=-1$.

Comment: @ Christian Blatter Thank you for your explanation but I don't understand how it is that you have decided to choose nk:=4(2k+1)^2?

Comment: @134785: By "reverse engineering". I wanted to make use of $\cos\bigl((2k+1)\pi\bigr)=-1$ for all $k\in{\mathbb Z}$. This enforces the particular choice of $n_k$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

How exactly are you coming up with the number -0.98? It's quite obvious that it *can't* be this, since there is an $n$ such that $-1\leq\cos(\pi\sqrt{n}/2)<-0.98.$ The periodicity of $\cos$ then allows you to take $n$ large enough so that $2/n$ is as small as you like.  Furthermore, the infimum cannot be less than $-1$, since $cos x\geq-1$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Now figure out what form $n$ must be in order to justify the previous statements.

Comment: Can i also ask you: inf s doesn't need to be part of a set but it does need to be contained in the set( in know not literally) in the sense that if we have s=(0,1) not including o or 1 inf s=0, where inf s is not part of the set but it has to take an extreme value of a set. I know this is not very well put but inf s basically has to take an extreme value of the set.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $|\cos x|<1$, and remember that $\cos x$ is periodic, so taking $n$ large enough will make $\frac{2}{n}\to 0$. The infimum should be $-1$.